# Using Blueprint CSS, how do I get text to wrap around an image div?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

I created the following wrapper div with a div inside it half the width to contain an image.

What I want is the text placed in the wrapper div to flow around the image div but it's either appearing on top of it or only to the side of it.

```
<div id="wrapper" class='span-8 last'>
<div id="image" class='span-4'>
</div>
</div>
```

Is there a change I could make to my Blueprint classes to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Did you place the text correctly after the image?

```
<div id="wrapper" class='span-8 last'>
    <div id="image" class='span-4'>
    </div>
    TEXT GOES HERE....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't posted any css so we don't know for sure what attributes are already set. Leaving things as they are in your example, if you add a `float:left;` to the image div, the text will flow around it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the style changes that the .span-4 makes. You might have to remove one of the declarations in there.

Couldn't you just create a separate CSS class for floating images or use an inline style that says "float:right" and whatever text-wrapping you want?

You might also have better luck getting your question answered on [the Pro Webmasters Q&A site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).